# Set value attribute for select box in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Im populating the options in a select box using angular js.The options as getting populated, but the value attribute for each option is automatically populated. How can that too be controlled ? ie I need to give the the name as its value.
This is my code

```
<select ng-model="plist" ng-options="item.name for item in items"><option value="">--Select Item--</option></select>

$scope.items = [
      {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'white', shade:'light'},
      {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
      {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
    ];
```

Comment: remove the ng-options from the select element, put a <options data-ng-repeat="item in items"/> inside the element and build the options yourself instead of using the ng-options directorive.

Answer (score 0):

To store object inside ng-model:

```
<select ng-model="plist" 
        ng-options="item as item.name for item in items">
            ...
```

To store only the value inside ng-model:

```
<select ng-model="plist" 
        ng-options="item.name as item.name for item in items">
            ...
```